# ExtJS evaluate server response with proxy writer

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Following scenario:

1. There is a store with the fields: title, content, created
2. A new record with title and content is added
3. Via Ajax proxy the new record is sent to the server
4. The Server automatically adds the created field and returns the whole record (with created field)

So after Step 4, how can i achieve, that the store automatically updates the new (synced) record with the server response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done automagically by ExtJS 4

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll should try more "Try and error" :)

Comment: Make sure you're writer is configured properly to parse whole record from server response.

Comment: adding to @sha comment, make sure your ID property is an int